# ¿Cuál opción enfatiza más la parte tecnológica: manual de usuario / de instrucciones / de teléfono / de celular?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Cuál de las opciones en la frase siguiente es mejor para enfatizar que el manual fue de un apartado, que la traducción fue relacionada con la tecnología?
El manual fue de celular.

> Traduje un manual de usuario / de instrucciones / de teléfono / de celular.

Comment: ¿A qué público va dirigido? En España *celular* no se usa y en Hispanoamérica no sé si se usa *teléfono móvil*.

Comment: Sí, sé que en España dicen móvil. En America Latina se usa celular. Bueno. Es un texto dirigido a todos. jeje Muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es dejar claro (en un currículum, por ejemplo) que las traducciones que has hecho son de temas tecnológicos, puedes añadir el adjetivo "**técnico**": "*manual **técnico** de usuario*". Con eso queda claro el aspecto tecnológico.
Las otras opciones que indicas, como "*manual de teléfono móvil*", también pueden valer. Si no quieres ser tan específico, una opción más genérica sería "*manual de dispositivo móvil*".

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por esta sugerencia; ha resuelto mi problema. Saludos.